# mod rewrite Subdomain to main domain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to make a mod rewrite for a blog I am moving from a subdomain to main domain and need to preserve all of the permalinks. (all 774 posts)

So for example:

blog.example.com/2014/04/new-blog-post/

will now be:

example.com/2014/04/new-blog-post/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_POST} ^blog.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```